# NSNotificationCenter. Send data from one to others ViewControllers Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm trying to show some data in a LastVC depending of the choose of the user in each view. I Let you the image of our App

[image]

I am using NSNotificationCenter but the labels in the lastVC do not change.

What is wrong?

@IBOutlet weak var colorLabelSelected: UILabel!

```
@IBOutlet weak var nextOutlet: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    nextOutlet.hidden = true



}


@IBAction func greenButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("setGreenColorID", object: nil)

    colorLabelSelected.text = "You have selected a green BG color"
    nextOutlet.hidden = false


}


@IBAction func blueButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("setGreenColorID", object: nil)

    colorLabelSelected.text = "You have selected a blue BG color"
    nextOutlet.hidden = false

}


@IBAction func pinkButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("setGreenColorID", object: nil)

    colorLabelSelected.text = "You have selected a pink BG color"
    nextOutlet.hidden = false

}
```

}

class ViewController2: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var nextOutlet: UIButton!


@IBOutlet weak var titleLabelSelected: UILabel!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    nextOutlet.hidden = true

}

@IBAction func newsButton(sender: AnyObject) {

     NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("setNewsThemeID", object: nil)

    titleLabelSelected.text = "You have selected News as title"
    nextOutlet.hidden = false

}


@IBAction func sportButton(sender: AnyObject) {

     NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("setSportThemeID", object: nil)

    titleLabelSelected.text = "You have selected Sport as title"
    nextOutlet.hidden = false

}



@IBAction func wealthButton(sender: AnyObject) {

     NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("setWealthThemeID", object: nil)

    titleLabelSelected.text = "You have selected Wealth as title"
    nextOutlet.hidden = false

}
```

}

The same with VC3

class lastViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var finalColorLabel: UILabel!


@IBOutlet weak var finalThemeLabel: UILabel!


@IBOutlet weak var finalRelevanceLabel: UILabel!





override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "setBlueColor:", name: "setBlueColorID", object: nil)
     NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "setGreenColor:", name: "setGreenColorID", object: nil)
     NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "setPinkColor:", name: "setPinkColorID", object: nil)


    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "setNewsTheme:", name: "setNewsThemeID", object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "setSportTheme:", name: "setSportThemeID", object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "setWealthTheme:", name: "setWealthThemeID", object: nil)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "setTenPoints:", name: "setTenPointsID", object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "setSevenPoints:", name: "setSevenPointsID", object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "setFivePoints:", name: "setFivePointsID", object: nil)




}


//setColors
func setBlueColor(notification: NSNotification) {

    finalColorLabel.text = "blue"


}


func setGreenColor(notification: NSNotification) {

    finalColorLabel.text = "green"


}

func setPinkColor(notification: NSNotification) {

    finalColorLabel.text = "pink"


}

//setTheme

func setNewsTheme(notification: NSNotification) {

    finalThemeLabel.text = "news"


}


func setSportTheme(notification: NSNotification) {

    finalThemeLabel.text = "sport"


}


func setWealthTheme(notification: NSNotification) {


    finalThemeLabel.text = "wealth"


}



//setRelevance

func setTenPoints(notification: NSNotification){

    finalRelevanceLabel.text = "ten"


}


func setSevenPoints(notification: NSNotification){

    finalRelevanceLabel.text = "seven"


}

func setFivePoints(notification: NSNotification){

    finalRelevanceLabel.text = "five"


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the lastVC even exist when you post notifications from the other ViewControllers? If you segue to it as a part of a normal **show** segue the view controller get's recreated every time you segue to it.

If you want to pass data from one viewController to the other you should probably do it in prepareForSegue. I'd approach it this way

1) create an object:

```
struct userSettings {
  var backgroundColor: NSColor?
  var title: String?
  var relevance: Int?
}
```

2) fill appropriate field in each ViewController

3) pass it in prepare for segue

```
  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let identifier = segue.identifier {
    switch identifier {
    case segueToController:
      if let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as? myControllerClass {
      viewController.userSettings = userSettings
      }
    default: break
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What if we want to pass something to  more than one Vc's?

Comment: In this case you'll probably need to split your code into a proper MVC. Create a userSettingsModel (should be a class, not a value type like struct) and pass a pointer when segueing to a ViewController. View controller will update the model with whatever user set and that's it.